# bulkcopy with primary key not working

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

I have a database table, with columns and a priamary key.

I want to do the bulkcopy, from a datatable in my c#.

When I have primary key in my table, I got exception because the table has 6 columns, while my datatable has just 5.

what should I do please?

Should I add the primary key to my datatable in my c#?

(if you need any code tell me pleae)

this is the datatable

```
private DataTable getBasicDataTable()
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Clear();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("customerID", typeof(int));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("firstName", typeof(string));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("lastName", typeof(string));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("showsNumber", typeof(int));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("visitNumber", typeof(int));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("cancellation", typeof(int));
            return dataTable;
        }
```

but in my database table, I have the exact same columns, but with extra `ID` primary key,

#### Note

when I delete my primary key in the database, everything works perfectly

Comment: We usually do fine with our psychic magic ball debugging abilities. But i think we'll need code for this one.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Okay I will post code

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I prefer to see the code in the entrails of a camel :-p

Comment: @Oscar please don't make fun

Comment: Is your Primary Key is set with Identity Specification `True`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov why you asked for the code ?

Comment: Is the customerID is your Primary Key or different one

Comment: @Rajesh it different one. it is `ID`

Comment: I didn't downvote the question, but ... dropping a PK just so you can bulkcopy data? ... Seems kinda extreme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution myself

```
bc.ColumnMappings.Add("customerID", "customerID");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("firstName", "firstName");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("lastName", "lastName");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("showsNumber", "showsNumber");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("visitNumber", "visitNumber");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("cancellation", "cancellation");
```

Comment: This didn't work for me until I had the column mapping set as well.

Comment: damn, I have 55 columns :/

Comment: I wish there was a less boring solution for this problem :)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`SqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.columnmappings(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Column mappings define the relationships between columns in the data source and columns in the destination.
>
> ...
>
> If the data source and the destination table have the same number of columns, and the ordinal position of each source column within the data source matches the ordinal position of the corresponding destination column, the ColumnMappings collection is unnecessary. However, if the column counts differ, or the ordinal positions are not consistent, you must use ColumnMappings to make sure that data is copied into the correct columns.

See the Example at [`SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopycolumnmapping(v=vs.110).aspx) for how to use it.

Comment: loooool, really thanks, but I just did my asnwer, it is the same as you said, I will accept your answer though, but could you tell me why someone downvote the question?

Comment: I cannot tell you why somebody downvoted, but I can tell you to stop worry about. Not worth it.